# Replacing "/" with "\" doesn't work

Tags: python

I am trying to replace `/` with `\` as below, but it doesn't work, why is that?

```
str = "images/companyPkg/Pkg/nib64/"
replaced_str = str.replace('//','\\')
print replaced_str
```

Comment: Because you're trying to replace `//` with \.

Comment: Why are you using `//`?  '/' doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: it seems weird that you would need to change the `/` character in something that looks like a path anyway ...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12288679/10077

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`'/'` does not need to be doubled. `'\'` is doubled because strings cannot end with `'\'`:

```
s = "images/companyPkg/Pkg/nib64/"
replaced_str = s.replace('/','\\')
```

Don't assign anything to the name `str`, `str` is a builtin (class for strings) in Python. Making an assignment will make the builtin name unusable later on in your code. You don't want that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to escape the `/` in python just the `\` so the following line should do the trick:

```
replaced_str = str.replace('/', '\\')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should double the back slash `\` because it is the escape character and used to provide a special meaning to the certain characters as for example `n` is **simple 'n'** but `\n` is a **new line**, but forward slash `/` is a simple character so you don't need to double it.

You should write
`replaced_str = str.replace('/','\\')`